# Canvas - make element do a smooth turn given radius and angle

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to figure out how to make an element move with JS in a canvas, here's what I have prepared: https://jsfiddle.net/ge1o2bt1/.

So for example, I want the constructor function on the "particle" to have a function called turn which you can pass angle, and radius and it will turn for example if it's going `x++; y+=0` after turning 90º it should go `x+=0; y++`.

Here's the code that moves the object (inside the constructor):

```
this.move = function(){
    this.x+=1;
};
```

then it's drawn on the canvas based on x and y position.
Thanks in advance, I tried a lot of things like using `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` or using `context.rotate` with `save()` and `restore()`. I'm not really good in math so I couldn't figure out how to do it.

EDIT: using some tutorial I could refactor the code and made this: https://jsfiddle.net/g2c9hf1p/. Now when you click, the object turns x degrees(I set it to 90) but you can't give the radius because it's dependant on the speed.

Comment: so, what do you want? where is the angle input?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable for the direction and an array with objects, whicht keeps the increments for the coordinates.

```
var direction = 0;
var directions = [{ x: 1, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 1 }, { x: -1, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: -1 }];
```

To change the coordinate, just add the direction.

```
this.move = function () {
    this.x += directions[direction].x;
    this.y += directions[direction].y;
};
```

For changing the direction, increment direction and limit by length.

```
window.addEventListener('click', function () {
    direction++;
    direction = direction % directions.length;
});
```

```js
function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

var t = 0;

function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

clearCanvas();

function circle(x, y, radius) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
}

var part = new Particle(0, height / 2);

var rotation = 0;

var direction = 0;
var directions = [{ x: 1, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 1 }, { x: -1, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: -1 }];

function loop() {
    part.move();
    part.draw();

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    t++;
}

function Particle(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = 'hsl(' + t + ',100%,50%)';
    this.radius = 1;

    this.move = function () {
        this.x += directions[direction].x;
        this.y += directions[direction].y;
    };

    this.draw = function () {
        this.color = 'hsl(' + t + ',100%,50%)';
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        circle(this.x, this.y, this.radius);
        ctx.fill();
    };
}

loop();

window.addEventListener('click', function () {
    direction++;
    direction = direction % directions.length;
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    clearCanvas();
});
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
body {  overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```